# Long equation in doubled column format journal

Tags: equations, line-breaking, two-column

How can I split the equation or somehow make it totally visible? (WileyNJD-v2.cls) you can download wiley format from https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/14678640/AMA-stix_New-1660139693240.zip

```
\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\articletype{research article}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom   

\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt} % set columns separation <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\title{Chained masteel fSFRC) beams}

\abstract[Abstract]{Due to the benefits of steel fiber reiDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atDue to the benefits of steel fiber reinforceement atnforceement at }

\maketitle


\twocolumn 


 \section{Introduction}\label{sec1}



 Significant efforts have been undertaken in recent years to increase the strength and ductility of concretsdggggggggggggggggggg erformance fiber-reinforced concrete (UHPFRC) structures possess exceptional ductility and stren in recent years to increase the strength and ductility of concretsdggggggggggggggggggg erformance fiber-reinfn in recent years to increase the strength and ductility of concretsdggggggggggggggggggg erformance fiber-reinfn in recent years to increase the strength and ductility of concretsdggggggggggggggggggg erformance fiber-reinf

\begin{equation}
\varphi_{k}(val)=\sum s\subseteq\left\{ x_{i},...,x_{n.}\right\} /\left\{x_{k}\right\} \frac{\mid s\mid!(n-\mid s\mid-1)!}{n!}\left(val\left(s\cup\left\{x_{k}\right\} -val(s)\right)\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution employs a `multline` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package which, in turn, is loaded automatically by the `WileyNJD-v2` document class. Note that I had to guess as to the scope of the `/` (division, right?) symbol; I've changed `/` to `\Big/` and placed tall parentheses around the material on the second line. Please advise if my guess was incorrect.

I've also gotten rid of all instances of `\left` and `\right` -- they do nothing except mess up the horizontal spacing -- and have replaced both instances of `\mid s\mid` with `|s|`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\articletype{research article}
\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom   
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt} 

%% new:
\usepackage{lipsum} %  filler text
\newcommand\val{\mathrm{val}}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn 

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\lipsum[1][1-4] % filler text
\begin{multline}
\varphi_{k}(\val)
=\sum s\subseteq\{ x_{i},\dots,x_{n} \} \Big/ \\
\Bigl(\{x_{k}\} \frac{|s|!\,(n-|s|-1)!}{n!}
\bigl(\val(s\cup\{x_{k}\} -\val(s))\bigr) \Bigr)
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1][5-8] % more filler text

\end{document}
```